# is there any hardware device to convert source code into machine language?

Tags: compilers, interpreters

Is there any hardware device inside computer that helps to convert high level language into machine, like compiler and assembler ?

Comment: Are you asking whether the processor in the computer is used to run the compiler and the assembler?  yes.

Comment: In a sense, the CPU *helps* by allowing the compiler and assembler to run. That is, anything software's doing is ultimately done by hardware. Of course, I think your real question is whether there's *special-purpose* hardware, to which I believe the answer is *no*.

Comment: Would the row of switches / buttons on the Altair (1000?) qualify?

Answer (score 7):

No, and yes.

The answer is "no", in the sense that the vast majority of computers have no hardware that does what you typically expect a compiler to do; compilers are written in software. Obviously this ultimately runs on hardware, but we're talking general-purpose hardware.

However, the answer is "yes", in the sense that the machine code that is actually executed often isn't the same as the machine code that a programmer sees (i.e. the instruction set architecture, or ISA for short). Almost all modern CPUs do some degree of dynamic translation of the "machine code" into a form that is more suited for out-of-order execution.

Intel/AMD-type CPUs, for example, translate machine code into RISC micro-operations (called "uops"). It is these instructions which are scheduled and executed.

ARM has something similar. Its ISA is much closer to the format that's executed, but ARM also features Thumb instructions, which are dynamically translated into "core" instructions. The short-lived Jazelle DBX/ThumbEE did a similar thing with direct execution of JVM bytecode.

Almost all modern high-performance CPUs do this to varying degrees. Indeed, there is a fuzzy line between "dynamic translation" and "instruction decoding".

Answer (score 1):

To complement the very good [answer by Pseudonym](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/31970/is-there-any-hardware-device-to-convert-source-code-into-machine-language/31972#31972) (this was initially
intended as a comment, but became long).

As Pseudonym said, all CPUs can be considered has having some form of
translation process of code into more elementary steps, of for more
elementary cicuit, and *there is a fuzzy distinction between "dynamic
translation" and "instruction decoding".*

But if you go one level up, you have [byte-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) interpreters. Byte code
interpreters translate byte-code (i.e. source code at this level) into
machine instructions. The first byte code interpreters were written as
software programs. Then people started making specilized computers
which looked like their machine code was the byte-code. They actually
had byte-code interpreters inside, implemented in [microcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode) residing on high-speed memory. Now again, the
line is fuzzy: is an unchanging program in microcode on high speed memory to be considered hardware or or precompiled
software. But then, in what sense would it be different from other
[programmable logic device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_device) found in various hardware pieces, and in
what sense would these be different from hardware assembled from
logical gates with a soldering iron. Actually [microcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode) is often *stored in a ROM (read-only memory) or PLA (programmable logic array) structure, or a combination of both.*

The concept of bytecode dates back to the 1960s, and it was much
developed for Pascal implementations in the 1970s as [p-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-code_machine) (often
understood at the time as *Pascal-code*, though meaning now *portable
code*) leading to what is probably the first byte-code machine: the
[Pascal MicroEngine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_MicroEngine) in 1979. Its *p-code was, effectively, its native machine language*.

Around the same time, the [Lisp machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine#Technical_overview) was developed, using microcode
to implement an instruction set specialized for Lisp.

To my knowledge, this is about as high as hardware will go in the code
ecology, but it does make some room for various translations: what is object code for one level is source code for the level below.  From a
conceptual point of view, there is no difference between hardware and
software as to what they can do. It is mostly an issue of flexibility,
speed, reliability and cost-effectiveness. And you prefer to have
highly complex structures in software so as to be able to debug them
and correct them: hardware bugs can be very expensive to deal with. These
parameters also fix the level of programmability from very hard
circuitry, to programmable logic, to microcode and read-only memory to standard
dynamically programmable memory that may contain the code for a compiler.

These remarks about hierarchical, multi-level translation structures
also apply to some extent at the program design level, when the translation from
general specification to architecture, to algorithms, to source code is done by humans. The same is or
can be true for other concepts such as memory management, caching, parallel
processing, communications.

**However**, this answer has been cheating a bit in the sense that it
talks only of interpretation, not compilation. Interpretation is
pretty much an on the fly translation process, but often (not always:
it can be memoized) executes the resulting code immediately without
memorizing it as a compiler would. Then, the question is only about
conversion, not memorization or compilers. Furthermore, interpreters are usually
also considered as [program translators](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Computer_Components,_The_Stored_Program_Concept_and_the_Internet/Fundamentals_of_Computer_Systems/Types_of_program_translator).

Comment: [This lecture slide set](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cis501-Fall05/lectures/02_isa.pdf) mentions (in the context of "semantic gap") under "Stranger than fiction": "People once thought computers would execute language directly" and "Fortunately, never materialized (but keeps coming back around)". [This abstract](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1217197) mentions "direct execution" high-level language computer architecture.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I have no access to this paper, and am not sure how to interpret the abstract. Also ACM
SIG newsletters are not peer-reviewed publications. The slides look
interesting, but I do not believe they contradict what I said. It is
probably the case though that specialized harware has been a recurring
dream that never really materialized durably, probably because porting
software is expensive and hardware evolves fast. Not a specialist, but
I suspect that C is the hardware lingua franca. But it is immaterial
from users point of view.  Whatever works. What do you think?

Comment: I was just bringing up that direct (hardware) execution of high level languages was proposed but never really had any practical application. Ditzel & Patterson's ["Retrospective on High-Level Language Computer Architecture"](http://www.cs.uccs.edu/~zbo/teaching/CS4520/Assignment/R1_HighLevel_Lang_CA_ditzel.pdf) (1980) presents a RISC view of HLLCA. Colwell et al.'s ["Performance Effects of Architectural Complexity in the Intel 432"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=16766176999232504757) presents some HLLCA-related issues from that particular implementation.

Comment: @PaulA.Clay I agree with you. It even started with the Burroughs machines
architecture in 1961 that were intended for Algol-like languages. I
do not think any was intended to execute source code directly, though
(possibly the Lisp machine, but I never used it and have some doubts).
I was only answering a question. I might have stressed that it mostly
failed, for good reasons (time cost of specialization vs fast
evolution). I preferred to give criteria, and the answer is long
already. The only apparent success are the graphics CPU, more a
computation model than a HLLCA. Do I say anything wrong?

Comment: No, you did not say anything wrong, I was merely pointing to further information. (I am fairly certain that none of the LISP machines directly executed source code.)

Comment: One thing I would add to this is that the Pentium trace cache stores uops, not IA32 instructions. In this sense, the IA32 instructions can be said to have been "compiled" on those CPUs.